# How to catch an exception when filtering a vaadin grid

Tags: java, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

Using vaadin (7.7.3)  I'm filtering a grid by name, this filtering takes a couple seconds to remove the objects from the `Grid` gui. And so, if I click on that timelapse a row of the `Grid` which is removed from the `Container`, it raises an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given item id (5422bef6-e472-4d3e-af54-316c52d373da) does not exist in the container
at com.vaadin.ui.Grid$AbstractSelectionModel.checkItemIdExists(Grid.java:1371)
at com.vaadin.ui.Grid$SingleSelectionModel.select(Grid.java:1460)
at com.vaadin.ui.Grid$SingleSelectionModel$1.select(Grid.java:1445)
```

I guess this is normal because it removes the objects from the `Container` and then it will propagate to the gui.

I have thought of catching the exception overwriting the `checkItemIdExists()` method in my `Grid` class but it would catch the exception for every situation and that is not the behavior I am looking for.

My question is: How can I capture this exception just in this case?

Comment: Are you asking how to unselect the element before using the filter? or are you asking how to avoid this exception?

Comment: Simply catch IllegalArgumentException..

Comment: Catching the exception is not possible. This exception is not launched in the application code. Seems that is launched by the vaadin component library when using the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround I have found, is to override the selection model of the grid in Vaadin to disable the `checkItemIdExists` method. This is the method that launches the exception you have.

```
import com.vaadin.ui.Grid.SelectionModel;
import com.vaadin.ui.Grid.SingleSelectionModel;

public class SingleSelectionModelNotChecked extends SingleSelectionModel implements SelectionModel {

    @Override
    protected void checkItemIdExists(Object itemId) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    // Nothing to do. No check is done, no exception is launched when the filter is applying. 
    }
}
```

You can now include this into your gird with:

```
setSelectionModel(new SingleSelectionModelNotChecked());
```

Of course, now the grid cannot check that the element selected in in the grid or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Viritin Add-on https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/viritin
it supports server side paging, Vaadin Grid will load all data from database or you will use your dataSource to send ContainerDataSource.